# SQL Server 2014 bulk insert not working

Tags: sql-server

Please excuse the newbie question, but I have an issue I haven't been able to work out. Trying to do a bulk insert of a `.csv` into a SQL Server 2014 table, and the last 2 columns are blank.  No matter what I've tried, I cannot get it to pick up any data (keep getting 0 rows affected).

File is below, as is the DDL for the table. Have tried with and without using a format file, as well as numerous versions of BULK INSERT, including using , and t as field terminators and  and r as row terminators. Any and all help is very much appreciated, this has got me totally stuck.

Have tried using just the format file, and also spelling everything out (numerous variations).

Thanks in advance!!

Table DDL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Expireds_New]
(
    [Address] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [text] NULL,
    [Zip] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [MLS#] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OMD] [date] NULL,
    [Followup_Date] [date] NULL,
    [First_Owner] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Second_Owner] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Phone1] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone2] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone3] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

FMT file:

```
12
15
1       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     1     Address                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     2     City                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       0       "\t"     3     State                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"     4     Zip                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       20      "\t"     5     MLS#                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       20      "\t"     6     Status                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       11      "\t"     7     OMD                            ""
8       SQLCHAR             0       11      "\t"     8     Followup_Date                  ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     9     First_Owner                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     10    Second_Owner                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"     11    Phone1                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"     12    Phone2                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"     13    Phone3                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     14    Email                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             0       0       "\r\n"   15    Remarks                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

File format (first 3 lines of csv):

```
Address1    City    State   Postal Code Gender  Extension   Fax Web Name    Company Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2  Phone Number 3  Email   Address2
139 27th St Del Mar CA  92014   150045904   Expired 11/2/2015       139 27th Street Llc     16195551212 16195551212 
1021 Costa Pacifica Way  2  Oceanside   CA  92054   150056483   Expired 11/1/2015       2000 Family Trust Nack      16195551212 16195551212 16195551212
```

Bulk Insert with Format File and parameters (I have used numerous variations of this statement, both with and without the format file):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_load_expireds_new] 
AS
BEGIN
    BULK INSERT Prospects.dbo.Expireds_New
    FROM 'C:\prospects\expireds_new_contacts.csv'
    WITH
        (KEEPNULLS,
         FORMATFILE = 'C:\Commands\expireds.FMT',
         FIRSTROW = 2,
         FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
         --ERRORFILE ='C:\Commands\err.txt'
        )
END
```

Bulk Insert using format file only:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_load_expireds_new] 
AS
BEGIN
    BULK INSERT Prospects.dbo.Expireds_New
    FROM 'C:\prospects\expireds_new_contacts.csv'
    WITH
        (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Commands\expireds.FMT'
         --ERRORFILE ='C:\Commands\err.txt'
        )
END
```

No errors are generated, both of these statements complete successfully.  However, when I execute either procedure, no data is imported. No errors are generated to the error file, or to SQL Server Management Studio.

Thank you for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I saved the first 3 lines of the csv file provided above and then opened it using Excel.  All the data was loaded into the first column.  The column data and column headers need to be separated by tabs.  One way to verify this is open up SQL Server Management Studio - Object Explorer.  Right click on your database, select Tasks, Import Data.  Then you can use the wizard features to confirm the csv file is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the newline character, instead of using ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', try using ROWTERMINATOR = **'0x0A'**